# nodejs puts post data into new json

Tags: json, node.js, http, post, request

When I sending post request by this code:

```
var data = '{data: 1111}'; // = JSON.stringify(message);

console.log('NotifySplitter: ' + data);

var options = cfg.splitterOptions;
options.headers['Content-Length'] = Buffer.byteLength(data)
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log("body: " + chunk);
    });
});

req.write(data);
req.end();
```

... and getting data by this code:

```
var express         = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.post('/', function(request, response){

    var query = request.body;
    console.log(request.body);
    response.end();

});
```

request.body contains:

> {'{data: 1111}': ''}

instead expected {data: 1111}. Is it normal? How to get normal data without replacing external {} in origin data before post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set up an appropriate content-type. If you're sending json, add `options.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'` to your request.

Also, `{data: 1111}` is not a JSON, it's JSON5. While it's better all around, it's not supported by default `express.bodyParser()`, so watch out for that.